# cx_Oracle query JSON CLOB with 'LIKE'

Tags: oracle, cx-oracle

I'm exploring cx_Oracle's JSON features within a CLOB. I have an index on the table that allows me to query for direct equality

```
SELECT * FROM mytable m WHERE m.jsonclob.jsonattribute = 'foo';
```

I'd like to be able to do the same thing with a `LIKE` statement.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable m WHERE m.jsonclob.jsonattribute LIKE 'foo.%';
```

Comment: Can you help us with link/ source or a  documentation on "cx_Oracle's JSON features" ? Or do you mean Oracle's JSON features in general?

Comment: Or do you mean Python's Oracle API, [cx_Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/python-091105.html). And also, what is your question? What is the problem? What is your desired result?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me with Oracle DB 12.2:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE j_purchaseorder_b (po_document CLOB CHECK (po_document IS JSON)) LOB (po_document) STORE AS (CACHE);

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO j_purchaseorder_b VALUES ('{"userId":2,"userName":"Bob","location":"USA"}');

1 row created.

SQL> SELECT pob.po_document.location FROM j_purchaseorder_b pob where pob.po_document.location LIKE 'US%';

LOCATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
USA
```

For reference check the Oracle JSON manual chapter [Query JSON Data.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/adjsn/query-json-data.html#GUID-119E5069-77F2-45DC-B6F0-A1B312945590)

A side note: the JSON team like recommending BLOB for storage for performance reasons.  Check the doc etc etc etc.